# XSLT merge multiple entries and add up numbers

Tags: xml, xslt

ich have following XML:

```
<item>
   <number>1</number>
   <value>2</value>
</item>
<item>
   <number>2</number>
   <value>22</value>
</item>
<item>
   <number>1</number>
   <value>4</value>
</item>
```

I want to transform the xml with xslt 1.0 to this:

```
<item>
   <number>1</number>
   <value>6</value>
</item>
<item>
   <number>2</number>
   <value>22</value>
</item>
```

The values from the same item number have to be added up and in the end i want to merge the elements of the same item. There can be n multible items with the same number. In this example the item with the number 1 is two times in the xml so those two will be one entry and the values(2,4) will be added up to 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very basic grouping question. In XSLT 1.0, grouping is done by using [the Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Start with an [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying)...

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Group all of the `item`'s by `number` by creating an [xsl:key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#key) matching `item` using `number`...

```
<xsl:key name="items" match="item" use="number"/>
```

From the context of the parent of all `item`'s (using `doc` as an example), output a copy of the element and apply templates to the first `item` in the group (and any attributes)...

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|item[count(.|key('items',number)[1])=1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Add a template that matches `item` and output a copy of it. Apply templates to any attributes and the `number` element. Then create a new `value` element with the sum of all `item`'s matching that key...

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|number"/>
    <value><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('items',number)/value)"/></value>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Full example...

**XML Input** (added a single root element `doc` to make the input well formed)

```
<doc>
    <item>
        <number>1</number>
        <value>2</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <number>2</number>
        <value>22</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <number>1</number>
        <value>4</value>
    </item>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="items" match="item" use="number"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|item[count(.|key('items',number)[1])=1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|number"/>
      <value><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('items',number)/value)"/></value>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc>
   <item>
      <number>1</number>
      <value>6</value>
   </item>
   <item>
      <number>2</number>
      <value>22</value>
   </item>
</doc>
```